# How to make grub as a Default(Primary) bootloader in a Legacy BIOS system(MBR)

Tags: boot, grub2, bios

I have removed windows Entirely and installed Ubuntu 20.04 only, by using the option "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu". The installation gets completed Successfully but after the Restart Blank Screen with "_" Blinking will come.

My laptop have Legacy BIOS.

Before I had a dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu) in which I used Easy BCD in Windows to create a boot menu entry for ubuntu, so by using that with the first boot menu if I use to select Ubuntu it use to redirect to Grub bootloader. As far I understood as there are no boot menu entry for primary bootloader nothing comes.

Is there any why I can get Grub as my Default bootloader without having Windows.

Comment: Which type of the partition table (MBR, GPT) you have on your disk ?

Comment: If you only have one install, you do not normally get grub menu. It just directly boots into Ubuntu. If BIOS you have to press/hold shift key just after BIOS screen and before grub menu would normally appear. If UEFI, you use escape key, but just press it perhaps more than once. Timing can be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

try booting to a rescue disc (or any live linux usb) and running:

```
grub2-install /dev/sda
```

(replace /dev/sda with your boot drive device if it is not sda)

Comment: Is it doing this from the terminal?

Comment: yes, from the terminal